# How to remove Itemid from url in JOOMLA 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have some modules on homepage which have article title with link that must be redirect on article page.

Problem is that if there is menu associated with article then when I click on the article title, the article opens correctly. But if there menu isn't associated with article, the article isn't open at all and redirected to again home page.

Module article links have Itemid, it is default Itemid added by joomla when i have remove that Itemid from url manually article open properly but with Itemid it is not.

Here's the site link i have working on please have a look

http://www.econewsindia.com/

Comment: can you give us an example link

Comment: What you're explaining here is expected behaviour.  Could you please explain what behaviour it is you're looking for?  It is common to add menu items in Joomla that are not used in any menus.  This gives you greater control over module assignment and url formation(SEF).

Answer (score 0):

What I found from your site is you do not have proper menu items created for article categories. Follow this procedure.

1. Create a new menus and name it as Articles Menu or whatever you like
2. Create a menu item for each "Top Level" article category under this menus (no need for sub categories). Use "Category List" or "Category Blog" menu item type - first one is preferred.
3. If you would like, you can show this menus on front-end using Menu Module but that is not necessary.

Now every article will have a proper item id associated with it and your articles will redirect properly.